# 74F86PC XOR does not work in 4 bit adder

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I made a 4 bit adder where one input is from user and the other from a gated master-slave R S Nor.

It seems that the XOR gates (note,  not just one) always give a floating output. I have pulled all inputs to ground through 1k ohm resistances, added bypass capacitors,  and ensured proper connections. What's wrong?

Information

Voltage -  6V

Uses ~11m wire

Base -  the soldering type breadboard with holes and solder already on the holes.

I'll give any other needed info ASAP. Thanks.

PS I'm not posting pictures as it's a jungle of wires and pretty much nothing can be understood from it.

EDIT

I connected an XOR gate on a solderless breadboard to see if my XOR gate was broken. But the moment I powered the circuit board in question, the XOR output went low. Seems this is true for all the 74F gates I use (74F02N NOR and the 74F86PC XOR), but not for the others (74HC08 AND and 74HCS32 OR and 74AC04PC NOT)

Pictures -

[image: The RSNOR Clocked Master-Slave Memory]
[image: 4Bit Adder]

Extra questions - where do I get to know what the letters in the names mean? I now know (from asking others) that HC shows CMOS components and from you that F is Fast, for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a schematic?  You must have built the jungle of wires from something

Comment: 6V? With FAST? That doesn't sound good...

Comment: The 74F86 is a bipolar TTL part, not CMOS. The 1K pull-down resistors may not pull the inputs low enough to be recognized as a Low - try a direct conection to Ground instead.  These parts have totempole outputs so cannot "float" - the outputs are probably High.  An output High may be as low as 2.5 volts. (read the datasheet "Electrical Characteristics" section)

Comment: 11 metres of wire?

Comment: I would like to see a picture of this mess...

Comment: I used 6V because otherwise the outputs were too low.  How can I test for damage? I'll add pictures soon.  The jungle came from repeating a one bit full adder 4 times and the RSNOR 4 times.  Didn't make the full schematic.

Comment: Also,  the problem persists even when the inputs are high.  So,  IDK if the problem is there.

Comment: Ok, added information. I can't add the RSNOR Scheme, Only 2 images allowed :P

Comment: Technically HC is HCMOS, which is a generational improvement over the original CMOS, given by C or the CD4k parts. And FAST is an acronym of Fairchild Advanced Schottky TTL.

Comment: Did you account for differences in pinout between '86, '02, and *all those other quad 2-input gates*?